# Printing unsigned char(BYTE) in Hex format in c++. Using std::cout

Tags: c++, char, hex, cout, unsigned

I've looked through all previous version of this topic and none have seemed to help.
I've got a value located in unsigned char called Offset.
When printing this with `printf("%02X\n", Offset);` It prints out the correct value which is 0x2B.
Though when I try with `std::cout << std::hex << Offset << std::endl;` It always prints a different value.
I have also tried:

```
std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)Offset << std::endl;
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(Offset) << std::endl;
```

Though none have seemed to print out the correct value.

Comment: [It should work](https://godbolt.org/z/tUp2Y4). The error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Evg You are correct thank you. I didn't even realise that there error wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

As you defined "Offset" like this `unsigned char Offset = 0x2B;`, Offset's type now is `unsigned char` and you cant not print a `unsigned char` variable as a `std::hex`.
You must first convert it to the `std::hex` type then print it.

```
#include <iostream >


int main() {

    unsigned char Offset = 0x2B;
    printf("%02X\n", Offset);
    std::cout << std::hex << Offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)Offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(Offset) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the OP already cast to unsigned, and also realized that the error is else where